# Actual file size on mac os x

Tags: linux, macos, file-management

I have a large number of folders that each contain quite a few files of varying sizes (from a few bytes to 400kb or so), mostly smaller ones. I need to get the *actual* (not the disk usage) size of these folders. Is there any way to do this with a command like 'du'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly standard for `ls` to show true file sizes by default, and I've just verified that.  So:

```
ls -l <yourfiles>
```

To tally up the totals:

```
ls -l <yourfiles> | awk '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

If your tally needs to include files in subdirectories, the common solution is to use `find` to invoke `ls`:

```
find <yourdir>/. -type f -exec ls -l '{}' \; | awk '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Looks good, but I get an error; "minimum blocksize is 512" :/ Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: I'm home at my mac now.  Confirmed that a bare "ls" returns the exact size of files (as it should, really).  Modified answer to remove superfluous options, which should clear up your error.

Answer (score 2):

To see the total of just one specific folder use:

> du -s /path_to/specific_folder/

To see to total of each folder in one specific folder use an asterisk:

> du -s /path_to/specific_folder/*

If you don't own all of the files in those directories use sudo to be sure everything is counted.

Edit: Ah, I understand what you are asking now. You want:

> du -sk /path_to/specific_folder/

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently (more or less). But it returns the "size on disk", not the actual file size. The difference is quite large in this case (40-70% depending on folder content).

Comment: -sk still reports disk usage, not actual file size :/

Answer (score 2):

You could ask for the Mac-world total (includes resource forks) like this:

```
# Put this in a shell function or script, 'macTotal'
osascript - "${1:-.}" <<\EOF | perl -Mbignum -lpe '$_+=0,"\n"'
on run {arg}
    alias POSIX file arg
    tell application "System Events" to get size of result
end run
EOF

$ macTotal ~/Library
4465742628
```

The AppleScript prints the number in scientific notation. The Perl code is a sloppy way to expand the scientific notation.

If you are OK with reading the numbers from the GUI, just open a folder's Info window in *Finder*. The reported size is the same as what *System Events* gives in the AppleScript.

---

If you just care about data forks, I would go with something similar to 
pra's answer, but using `stat` instead of `ls` and `xargs` instead of `-exec` for a bit more efficiency.

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f %z | awk '{t+=$1}END{print t}'
4461971024
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run `wc -c` on each of the files.  This should return the number of characters in each file. It might take a while, since it actually reads through each file and counts the characters.